# Computing a scalar from UV coordinates in Cycles nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I have a .obj mesh loaded with given UV coordinates. I'd like to color the mesh using its UV coordinates, similarly to [this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface#mediaviewer/File%3aRiemann_sqrt.jpg). I think the correct way is to first compute a scalar out of the uv coordinates, something like `u*v`, and then connect that scalar to the hue value of a HSV node. Thing is, I don't know which module can I use to take the UV Map's output and turn it into a scalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the UV coordinates from a Texture Coordinates or from an Attribute Node, separate the three components of the vector using a Separate RGB node, and use this to map colors to your BSDF.

[image: Colors from UVs node setup]

[image: Colors from UVs result]

Comment: Suggest you remove the muted node from the screenshot, in case it confuses anyone

Comment: I left it intentionally, because OP wanted to multiply the U and V coordinates together, but I muted it because it looked like it wasn't needed to reproduce the reference picture.